# How can I test if my Tic Tac Toe A.I. is perfect?

Tags: python, recursion, artificial-intelligence, greedy

I made a tic tac toe A.I. Given each board state, my A.I. will return 1 exact place to move. (Even if moves are equally correct, it chooses same one every time, it does not pick a random one)

I also made a function that loops though all possible plays made with the A.I.

So it's a recursive function that lets the A.I. make a move for a given board, then lets the other play make all possible moves and calls the recursive function in it self with a new board for each possible move.

I do this for when the A.I goes first, and when the other one goes first... and add these together. I end up with 418 possible wins and 115 possible ties, and 0 possible loses.

But now my problem is, how do I maximize the amount of wins? I need to compare this statistic to something, but I can't figure out what to compare it to.

Comment: @JakobBowyer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHWjlCaIrQo

Comment: @hammar http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uVunn6Vux4

Comment: If it's perfect, it can never loose if it starts.

Comment: @GolezTrol No, you're wrong. That does not prove it's perfect, only that it's good. For it to be perfect, if has to has win at all possibilities. It could be that my AI ties at some of them instead of wins.

Comment: I didn't say it is perfect if it never looses. I said, *if* it is perfect, it never looses. So all you can deduct from that, is that if it looses a game it started, then it's not perfect, but not the other way around. Not very useful, I agree, so I'm glad I didn't post it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read article on wikipedia? [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)

Number of terminal positions

When considering only the state of the board, and after taking into account board symmetries (i.e. rotations and reflections), there are only 138 terminal board positions. Assuming that X makes the first move every time:

- 91 unique positions are won by (X)
- 44 unique positions are won by (O)
- 3 unique positions are drawn

Number of possible games

Without taking symmetries into account, the number of possible games can be determined by hand with an exact formula that leads to 255,168 possible games. Assuming that X makes the first move every time:

- 131,184 finished games are won by (X)
- 77,904 finished games are won by (O)
- 46,080 finished games are drawn

You may generate 138 terminal board positions from first paragraph

or

Yo may run enough tests on random fields and compare your results with statistics from here [link](http://www.se16.info/hgb/tictactoe.htm)

```
Win in 5 moves    1440     0.6%
Win in 6 moves    5328     2.1%
Win in 7 moves    47952   18.8%
Win in 8 moves    72576   28.4%
Win in 9 moves    81792   32.1%
Draw              46080   18.1%    
Total             255168 100.0%
```

Comment: how do you compare 131,184 wins to 418 wins? How do u compare these statistics to my results, that is my question.

Comment: make 91+44+3=138 board setups from first paragraph. Run AI. Compare wins/losses/drawn count.

Comment: @BlazArt you may generate them: direct search + some restrictions on symmetry and field rotation. Or you still make it brut force and compare to this http://www.se16.info/hgb/tictactoe.htm (link from wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

You could actually brute force the game, and prove that every time there is a winning strategy, your A.I. picks the correct move. Then, you could prove that for every position, your A.I. picks the move which maximizes the chances of having a winning strategy, assuming the other player is playing randomly. There are not that many possibilities, so you should be able to eliminate all of them.

You could also significantly diminish the space of possibilities by assuming the other player is actually slightly intelligent, e.g. always tries to block a move which results in immediate victory.

Comment: 255168 games. Ok. You have some results, f.e. 51% wins, 40% losses, 9% draw. Is it good or bad?

Answer (score 0):

One issue with akaRem's answer is that an optimal player shouldn't look like the overall distribution. For example, a player that I just wrote wins about 90% of the time against someone playing randomly and ties 10% of the time. You should only expect akaRem's statistics to match if you have two players against each other playing randomly. Two optimal players would always result in a tie.